# php - populate products for every field in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to populate the customers info in the table. I have acheived that with the code below. My problem is that in the last column I have the list of products with checkbox. The way how I coded it populates only for the first field(customer) in the table. I want it to have it with the unique id for every field as I'm planning to pass the POST function, create a row in SQL where I can assing the product to the customer. Any ideas ho to achieve this? Thanks

```
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="list" id="assign">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">First Name</td>
      <td class="left">Last Name</td>
      <td class="left">E-mail</td>
      <td class="left">Assign Product</td>
       </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4" class="left">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
      }else{
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
          echo "<tr><td class='left'>{$row['firstname']}</td><td class='left'>{$row['lastname']}</td><td class='left'>{$row['email']}</td><td><div class='layer'><p class='heading'>Edit</p>";
        }
      }
       if( !( $selectRes2 = mysql_query( $selectSQL2 ) ) ){
    echo 'Retrieval of data from Database Failed - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();
  }else{  }
   ?> 

   <div class='area'>
   <div class='scrollbox'>
   <?php
  if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes2 )==0 ){
        echo '<div>No Rows Returned</div>';
      }else{
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes2 ) ){
          echo "<div id='inline'><input type='checkbox'></input>{$row['name']}</div>";
         } echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'></input>";
      } 
          ?>            
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, just enter the equally magical "fix it" code. That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over thinking it, just add the id to the name of the check box, you can even prefix it with something like 'CHK_' and parse it out with the code that handles the form posts.

```
    echo "<div id='inline'><input type='checkbox' name='CHK_{$row['id']}'></input>{$row['name']}</div>";
```